# Confused using sleep and sleep in

Tags: prepositions

Can both sentences be used?

1. > I need a bed to sleep in.
2. > I need a bed to sleep.

Comment: [***sleep in***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sleep-in) also has idiomatic usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I need a bed to sleep in.**

You're looking for lodgings or a place to spend the night.

**I need a bed to sleep.**

You don't sleep very well on the floor, or on a cot or sofa; you require the comfort of a bed.

**I need some music to fall asleep by.

I need some music to fall asleep.**

**I need a pen to write with.

I need a pen to write.**

P.S.  Phrases following this pattern, with the preposition at the end, are parsed as noun phrases, with the infinitive-phrase complementing the noun at the head:

- *words to live by* ... words by which to live aka words for living | living words
- *shoes to run in* ... shoes in which to run  aka shoes for running |running shoes
- *light to read by*... light by which to read aka light for reading | reading light

So that noun-phrase becomes the {direct object} of "need":

I need {shoes to run in}.
I need  {shoes in which to run}.

On the other hand, phrases in this pattern:

- *a bed to sleep*
- *a pen to write*
- *music to fall asleep*

the to-infinitive chunk functions like a so-called "zero"-conditional clause:

*I need a bed to sleep = To sleep, I need a bed. If I want to sleep...*

*I need a pen to write = To write, I need a pen.  If I want to write...*

*I need music to fall asleep = To fall asleep, I need music. If I want to fall asleep...*

Answer (score 0):

TRomano put it well. Both are acceptable in my mind, although the connotation is different. You may wish to bear in mind that a lot of teachers will take exception to ending a sentence in a preposition. This is one of those arbitrary no-no's that English writing and language teachers love.

However, I would simply say "I need a bed." It will be presumed you need to sleep. Otherwise the subject would be "we" and really, you wouldn't really be obliged to tell people why the bed was needed.